# How to store data for each room on socket.io?

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I need to connect two clients (Android and Webview, each client is the same user) to one socket room and manage the data.

Two clients of the same user must be connected and data can be managed in one room. In addition, two clients must be connected to one room, even if traffic is distributed using multiple nodes.

Previously, data was managed by declaring a Map variable in one typecript file. However, unlike the past, the method has become unavailable, separating multiple event listeners on a file-by-file basis.